# Disable Particular Modal On Particular Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I Have A File named as `modal.php` Which Contains Two Modal

1. Login Modal
2. Feedback Modal

Login Modal Runs in Every 5 Seconds if user isn't logged in.and feedback modal opens on click.

And on My website i have 20 pages and in all pages i have included `modal.php`  So the problem i getting is in those 20 pages i have a page named with `signin.php`. i also include here an `modal.php`

So here is code for signin so i dont want to show signin modal here.
So how can i do that ?

Modal Opening Code in modal.php is

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['loginuser'])){ ?>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#signup_mask_popup').modal("show");
    }, 5000);
```

And I Tried

```
<?php if(basename(__FILE__) != 'free-listing-new.php') { ?>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#signup_mask_popup').modal("show");
    }, 5000);
<?php } ?>
```

But This Not working and modal will be shown. i think its maybe because file is included. So What do i have to do

Comment: its strange..! no one here to answer the question. ? is my question is not following stackoverflow/howtoask ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your trouble lies someplace else.  Your code works.  Here is how I tested the same. I included the modal in a modal.php only.

```
        <script>

        $(window).on("load", function () {

        <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['loginuser'])){ ?>

            console.log($('#signup_mask_popup'));
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#signup_mask_popup').modal("show");
            }, 5000);

           <?php  
            $cookie_name = "loginuser";
            $cookie_value = "John Doe";
            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day 
           ?>

        <?php }else { ?>
            console.log("cookie is set.");
        <?php } ?>


        <?php if(basename(__FILE__) != 'free-listing-new.php') { ?>
            console.log("here");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#signup_mask_popup').modal("show");
            }, 5000);
        <?php } ?>                


        });

    </script>
```